# Error when creating a pivot table using VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I'm trying to create a pivot table using VBA code. But it always show up the Run-time error '5'

```
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

SrcData = "Sheet1!" & Range("B2:M4").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)

StartPvt = "Sheet2!" & Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)

Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(StartPvt, "PivotTable1")
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: See my answer and code below, is your PivotData starts from 2nd row (`Range("B2:M4")`) ? if you have your headers in the first row, you need them as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will `Set pvt` in case it's already created (from previous code runs), and just updates the PivotTable with the updated `PivotCache`.

If "PivotTable1" does not exist yet in "Sheet2", then creat it in "Sheet2".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pivot()

Dim PvtSht          As Worksheet
Dim DataSht         As Worksheet    
Dim pvtCache        As PivotCache
Dim pvt             As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt        As String
Dim SrcData         As String

Set DataSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set PvtSht = Worksheets("Sheet2")

SrcData = "Sheet1!" & DataSht.Range("B2:M4").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)

' Set the Pivot Cache
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set pvt = PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' check if "PivotTable1" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If pvt Is Nothing Then    
    ' create a new "PivotTable1" in "Sheet2" sheet
    Set pvt = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    pvt.ChangePivotCache pvtCache
    pvt.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```